# How delete duplicate values in array actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

my arr4 array values are 11,11,11,12,12,12. I want to delete duplicate values and i want to get output 11,12 (after delete duplicate values).but using this code I  got output 12 only

```
 var g:int = 0;
    var arr4:Array = new Array();
        while(g < arr4.length) {
       while(g < arr4.length+1 && arr4[g] == arr4[g+1]) {
           arr4.splice(g, 1);
       }
        g++;
        }
```

Please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997822/flash-as3-how-do-i-remove-duplicates-in-an-array

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First sort array if it is not sorted

```
var arr4:Array = [10,10,11,11,11,12,12];

for ( var i = arr4.length -1; 1 <= i; --i )
{
    if ( arr4[i-1] == arr4[i] )
    {
        arr4.splice(i-1,1);
    }
}

trace( arr4 );
```

output 10,11,12

Comment: If this answer satisfy you pls mark as correct.

Comment: just an FYI, this requires a sorted array to work correctly.

Comment: As I say in the begging of my answer "First sort array.." It is clear enough the this method works with sorted array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much cleaner much faster way

```
    function myFilter(element:*, index:int, arr:Array):Boolean {
        return (index==arr.lastIndexOf(element));
    }

    var arr4:Array = new Array(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,3, 3, 3);
    arr4= arr4.filter(myFilter)
    trace('numbers filtered:' + arr4)
```

[EDIT]

Here is some test code to compare the speeds.
This may not be the best test but it does show that the filter method takes about .02% of the time then the looping method.

```
function getArray():Array{
    return [1,8,4,6,1,1,10,0,7,5,8,3,8,6,0,6,7,4,4,5,1,6,2,4,7,1,5,1,0,7,4,7,4,4,1,5,5,9,0,7,6,10,4,10,9,4,3,8,2,0,10,8,2,1,1,3,0,4,1,4,8,8,8,2,9,3,0,8,10,3,4,8,1,4,9,9,9,8,1,5,8,1,9,1,7,4,1,4,7,5,4,0,1,8,0,1,9,8,10,9,9,9,2,10,1,2,5,3,7,4,8,0,6,9,8,6,6,9,8,3,4,7,3,1,2,8,1,0,9,5,8,2,7,7,8,2,4,7,2,9,10,7,2,3,2,8,1,1,9,1,7,5,7,8,9,10,8,2,2,7,2,3,7,1,7,5,9,9,3,5,2,4,1,9,8,9,4,8,9,6,8,4,10,4,9,8,7,7,9,8,0,1,7,2,0,5,6,2,4,10,8,4,4,0,3,6,0,4,0,9,8,3,7,3,10,9,6,9,8,3,8,10,2,5,4,6,3,5,7,2,8,0,3,5,9,5,1,3,9,10,10,6,5,2,4,1,1,9,2,6,3,2,5,8,2,3,3,4,2,5,10,9,10,1,5,8,4,6,1,5,1,10,4,6,9,9,0,5,10,6,5,7,10,5,3,6,2,1,7,9,0,2,2,7,10,8,7,5,4,10,3,3,2,7,7,3,5,3,1,9,4,0,2,3,7,2,1,9,2,2,4,1,2,2,4,9,5,2,2,9,7,6,8,3,6,3,5,6,8,0,2,10,1,1,5,3,8,7,3,3,4,2,7,1,7,3,7,5,1,2,2,8,0,1,4,4,1,7,2,8,3,1,1,10,4,4,7,6,9,2,6,4,1,7,2,4,5,8,8,7,8,8,6,9,1,8,1,2,1,7,3,1,9,9,6,6,2,8,6,3,1,9,2,8,5,1,6,3,5,4,9,0,1,8,6,2,6,5,1,4,8,7,10,5,2,1,9,7,10,0,2,9,0,2,2,4,1,6,9,8,10,9,1,4,8,0,9,5,6,3,5,2,7,0,9,5,5,8,9,6,6,8,4,6,1,5,7,5,5,2,8,1,6,1,8,7,8,9,5,1,5,6,8,8,6,2,8,8,9,1,1,8,2,4,1,8,10,10,3,7,7,6,6,2,7,9,6,9,7,6,2,1,1,3,2,6,7,2,6,1,6,1,5,9,4,9,8,7,5,6,5,7,10,2,8,3,5,1,2,5,3,7,9,0,7,2,9,10,9,9,6,5,4,0,7,9,4,3,9,9,8,4,3,8,10,6,10,4,4,4,7,2,3,6,5,3,8,7,8,5,3,0,4,6,5,8,6,2,5,1,9,3,7,10,7,1,5,8,7,10,5,8,6,
    6,4,6,5,5,6,9,0,6,6,4,5,7,4,2,3,7,10,3,8,1,1,3,7,5,5,6,6,0,6,6,0,5,6,10,2,9,7,9,4,10,3,5,3,8,6,3,5,8,6,8,8,8,4,5,3,9,4,0,6,1,1,7,0,1,5,7,7,5,5,1,8,10,2,8,1,7,6,4,5,1,2,8,4,4,3,2,9,5,1,1,8,9,7,1,8,6,3,0,6,7,6,10,7,4,2,9,3,4,9,2,1,5,4,9,4,5,7,9,3,1,6,9,1,9,3,5,2,3,8,9,3,6,8,2,7,2,1,9,4,9,9,4,10,8,3,1,8,7,4,6,3,2,9,7,2,10,0,8,0,9,7,2,10,1,4,5,10,7,3,3,3,9,0,8,7,9,8,5,0,9,3,2,6,2,7,7,9,2,10,0,6,5,3,6,3,5,2,6,3,1,1,3,8,1,2,10,7,1,8,3,3,3,8,5,6,7,4,7,5,7,2,5,6,5,8,1,10,1,7,4,2,9,9,5,8,8,2,0,2,6,8,8,7,9,7,1,7,9,4,3,6,1,7,4,7,10,2,5,1,4,1,3,9,10,6,1,7,6,0,5,2,7,6,8,3,5,7,1,10,10,8,5,5,8,4,10,5,1,8,7,0,2,5,5,1,1,2,6,7,2,2,1,8,9,2,5,3,7,8,5,8,1,8,2,8,2,7,5,2,3,1,5,9,2,8,4,1,1,0,8,7,1,6,3,9,1,4,4,2,8,2,8,7,8,4,8,9,9,7,4,3,2,1,1,7,7,3,10,3,8,6,9,7,4,5,0,8,2,2,7,10,3,9,8,6,1,7,7,7,9,6,1,4,10,6,0,2,4,0,5,5,5,9,4,1,8,8,4,9,1,7,8,6,9,4,0,0,3,3,5,5,7,1,7,10,9,0,0,6,6,5,7,2,2,9,2,2,2,1,10,9,1,7,8,7,7,2,7,2,0,8,4,10,9,9,8,5,4,7,2,2,9,6,4,9,9,2,2,2,9,5,2,5,3,2,5,7,4,4,5,3,7,6,5,1,9,8,10,1,7,8,5,7,8,1,4,9,5,4,10,3,4,2,8,5,4,3,5,5,3,7,7,8,4,5,3,2,10,9,5,5,1,10,8,8,8,6,10,3,8,0,7,10,2,2,6,3,0,7,4,9,2,6,1,0,10,5,2,2,0,5,5,2,7,5,8,3,9,6,8,9,8,9,8,5,9,4,9,7,10,5,1,7,6,9,1,1,2,3,4,2,5,3,3,2,9,10,0,0,2,4,0,3,0,8,5,1,5,4,5,9,9,9,10,5,6,8,5,2,7,7,6,6,6,8,1,0,6,9,3,1,9,5,4,2,1,1,10,1,3,4,5,7,4,8,3,8,5,4,10,0,6,1,7,1,9,8,0,0,9,4,6,3,1,8,0,2,4,10,6,6,5,5,7,1,8,4,5,6,0,3,7,1,2,9,3,10,4,1,1,10,9,7,1,4,8,6,3,0,7,7,9,8,9,1,8,6,10,7,7,5,1,6,8,6,5,9,2,5,1,1,8,1,6,4,6,7,10,1,1,
    1,8,10,5,4,4,3,9,7,5,4,8,5,5,10,8,7,7,3,5,8,6,7,8,1,0,0,3,5,8,4,2,7,10,8,3,0,2,7,5,2,5,1,5,8,1,6,1,10,2,3,6,9,7,1,1,1,3,6,5,6,0,9,2,3,2,3,6,9,8,4,10,2,1,10,8,4,6,8,4,7,9,6,5,1,9,9,5,6,10,7,4,1,3,1,4,5,8,3,3,5,9,9,6,9,1,8,2,9,2,9,6,5,10,9,0,1,8,6,1,8,1,1,9,8,1,7,5,9,5,9,1,7,5,9,10,1,0,10,3,0,9,7,5,10,8,7,0,2,1,3,6,5,3,5,9,2,2,8,3,7,8,4,2,5,10,4,7,6,1,7,6,2,2,7,0,2,1,3,8,3,2,4,10,2,8,8,10,6,0,6,7,9,2,5,5,1,2,4,5,4,1,5,9,5,0,9,2,5,4,0,4,7,9,3,4,9,0,9,3,10,9,0,9,6,4,7,5,6,0,5,8,9,1,4,0,9,4,3,0,7,6,1,9,3,6,5,6,7,3,4,2,6,2,7,8,3,9,1,10,10,10,3,0,6,4,4,3,7,8,3,2,4,8,2,2,3,6,7,9,5,2,7,4,1,1,5,3,8,3,9,2,5,2,8,1,3,9,2,0,5,7,5,7,9,6,1,4,1,9,2,5,5,10,7,3,4,4,3,6,6,2,8,4,4,4,3,5,6,9,8,5,7,4,3,1,9,7,8,2,3,6,2,6,4,4,0,8,9,8,4,9,2,3,8,5,2,4,6,2,6,6,6,3,9,10,5,7,6,9,2,5,7,3,2,4,5,9,3,0,5,10,1,10,4,9,6,3,9,7,5,7,9,7,5,10,3,5,1,6,1,8,9,7,3,6,2,0,1,8,2,5,5,5,3,10,4,5,5,1,8,2,0,6,2,8,1,7,10,3,0,1,0,8,1,2,5,5,3,4,2,7,3,5,1,7,7,9,9,5,4,8,7,7,2,8,8,10,2,10,9,8,5,2,3,9,3,5,10,10,7,3,7,8,7,10,5,6,4,6,9,8,8,7,2,7,3,4,2,6,8,1,9,10,5,10,4,1,9,4,6,3,10,10,1,1,2,6,2,2,4,6,5,7,6,4,9,5,7,5,6,8,3,1,1,8,6,4,8,6,7,8,10,1,0,7,7,5,2,10,10,4,9,7,3,8,6,8,6,1,1,9,4,6,0,5,3,9,1,4,7,5,9,
    3,10,6,9,6,6,4,0,0,2,4,7,2,8,0,9,4,3,3,4,6,5,0,3,2,2,2,8,3,10,10,1,6,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,7,9,6,9,6,2,3,8,6,2,8,3,2,2,10,2,5,0,2,9,4,8,4,8,2,4,7,4,3,9,9,2,7,0,9,9,9,7,5,3,7,6,6,0,3,9,6,4,5,5,7,2,2,5,0,9,5,0,7,0,8,9,6,8,4,3,6,2,0,6,6,3,8,3,3,0,2,6,3,8,10,5,3,4,6,4,1,7,4,8,1,4,3,4,4,3,9,10,5,8,3,6,0,4,6,3,5,4,1,2,10,5,8,7,4,1,8,2,8,4,9,2,1,6,4,2,10,7,3,3,6,0,3,4,0,3,5,3,2,3,5,5,9,9,1,6,1,10,3,3,6,6,4,3,3,10,4,5,4,4,6,10,10,8,9,9,4,6,7,8,4,2,1,3,4,6,4,4,6,3,3,4,9,2,6,9,4,1,7,4,7,4,4,2,10,5,9,2,8,6,5,7,9,6,0,2,4,9,6,9,7,10,7,4,0,9,8,2,8,8,7,6,2,0,7,3,7,2,6,10,1,2,6,2,2,1,9,4,1,6,0,6,4,10,1,4,8,3,5,0,9,7,8,6,3,0,5,7,10,7,7,8,4,5,8,2,7,6,0,6,5,0,4,3,9,2,4,8,10,2,6,6,5,5,9,6,2,1,2,1,7,8,9,9,7,1,0,3,2,2,8,3,9,7,10,9,1,4,3,9,1,6,1,2,9,1,1,3,5,0,3,6,10,9,1,7,10,7,9,3,2,2,1,1,8,4,1,2,6,2,8,2,0,3,6,5,6,6,9,6,8,9,3,6,10,0,0,9,5,1,5,8,9,3,3,6,6,7,5,5,8,4,9,1,7,8,6,2,9,4,1,8,3,5,1,5,8,4,3,6,3,7,5,6,0,1,4,4,7,9,2,3,3,0,2,1,3,7,8,3,9,2,2,1,2,9,9,2,10,10,5,9,3,3,7,8,9,9,5,8,2,0,8,9,6,4,3,0,4,7,7,0,3,4,8,1,7,5,8,2,8,1,4,7,1,6,9,4,9,8,3,9,1,5,1,5,7,5,4,9,4,5,5,9,2,8,5,3,7,1,5,8,6,9,8,1,6,9,1,9,3,0,1,3,9,9,4,1,1,7,4,4,8,5,10,3,9,2,5,3,5,7,10,5,1,9,9,3,7,1,7,7,10,5,5,8,3,4,4,7,2,9,6,2,3,9,7,6,4,8,8,3,1,4,9,10,9,6,6,10,9,8,3,1,8,2,1,7,5,6,4,3,10,6,9,7,9,6,7,6,2,10,1,8,7,7,4,4,0,6,3,1,1,9,6,3,2,5,1,4,0,5,4,10,2,2,8,4,9,0,3,5,4,3,2,9,3,1,10,1,0,9,2,9,8,4,10,6,10,1,2,3,4,2,6,7,5,9,1,7,1,9,5,1,10,7,1,0,1,3,7,0,9,8,3,3,3,5,7,4,9,6,5,6,1,6,10,10,7,5,8,5,2,8,6,5,1,3,2,5,5,7,2,
    4,2,1,4,3,4,9,4,9,4,9,7,3,0,10,4,9,5,2,9,8,3,9,5,1,1,9,9,1,3,6,2,6,2,0,9,8,5,7,10,3,5,5,5,4,6,1,3,8,6,5,1,9,9,9,8,4,9,8,1,6,10,1,7,9,7,9,4,9,10,2,8,6,3,6,7,7,1,2,2,3,1,8,1,2,8,10,8,7,4,1,5,3,6,9,1,3,3,7,8,3,4,3,6,1,9,4,3,1,10,9,1,7,8,0,9,9,10,7,4,1,2,5,0,9,8,6,8,9,2,5,0,2,5,6,7,2,5,6,2,3,2,7,1,10,7,9,3,1,9,4,10,6,1,6,8,4,7,9,2,0,2,9,8,8,6,10,7,2,6,8,9,3,6,9,4,4,0,8,3,2,6,6,1,3,9,7,1,10,9,2,5,10,3,6,5,10,3,8,1,7,9,2,8,4,4,4,5,10,2,3,9,6,0,4,0,7,7,8,2,6,4,9,4,4,0,10,5,1,10,0,8,5,8,4,4,6,2,3,6,2,4,0,1,5,6,0,4,10,7,10,7,6,3,2,5,1,5,5,7,4,1,2,0,9,7,2,9,7,3,3,0,1,6,2,7,2,0,5,1,0,4,3,5,5,3,1,7,2,1,5,6,10,3,4,0,9,4,2,4,8,4,10,5,3,5,4,7,3,2,6,1,0,7,8,4,2,9,1,2,6,4,3,7,10,6,7,10,9,2,7,8,6,3,0,1,7,7,0,1,2,4,3,4,5,9,1,4,8,7,2,7,7,3,1,5,7,4,8,1,7,6,9,8,10,5,1,2,5,1,0,2,2,4,9,1,3,5,7,2,5,2,1,9,5,3,4,10,4,8,4,5,3,7,2,6,2,2,2,3,5,5,2,5,4,2,2,5,6,4,2,7,4,1,1,8,5,10,7,2,5,2,4,6,1,4,4,1,6,1,8,8,6,0,4,8,2,3,10,8,3,3,1,10,4,2,7,5,7,10,5,7,0,5,8,4,3,8,7,5,3,0,8,10,2,7,10,10,5,6,1,7,5,1,9,8,7,0,8,1,5,1,2,0,1,3,6,1,9,9,7,4,8,2,4,6,9,8,6,6,9,3,7,4,0,7,1,2,9,0,4,4,6,8,8,7,5,6,9,5,0,9,4,2,8,7,4,8,3,9,1,1,1,3,6,2,2,4,6,10,10,1,8,1,1,8,7,7,4,3,3,6,5,4,7,2,10,1,10,9,4,7,2,1,8,5,5,1,1,0,2,3,5,0,9,2,6,8,2,6,8,5,0,9,9,9,4,6,2,2,7,10,9,3,5,3,6,6,5,9,5,9,2,6,1,3,6,4,4,9,5,3,2,3,0,6,5,0,6,4,4,0,9,1,7,4,2,5,8,4,3,1,2,7,2,2,7,3,7,4,10,2,10,2,3,9,0,9,1,4,3,1,4,8,3,2,6,10,0,3,1,2,0,2,2,5,8,6,3,1,0,0,5,7,2,7,1,10,5,9,4,2,7,3,0,5,4,4,6,7,2,3,7,2,6,10,4,6,6,5,8,5,10,3,2,5,2,1,1,7,2,1,
    8,4,1,5,7,2,8,7,5,3,2,10,6,2,9,2,8,3,7,0,7,1,5,7,4,2,9,6,4,3,1,2,8,3,7,2,0,2,10,10,6,7,2,6,6,6,6,9,7,10,10,5,5,2,0,10,7,6,2,1,9,5,7,10,2,6,4,7,4,10,2,6,5,5,9,1,5,7,3,4,2,8,2,0,5,4,1,10,6,7,9,2,7,10,8,7,1,9,7,9,3,3,7,7,7,4,9,5,8,2,9,9,6,5,1,3,5,4,4,9,1,8,6,9,10,8,8,10,8,2,2,10,1,4,8,5,8,3,0,3,9,6,8,2,8,1,2,3,5,5,6,0,2,8,3,6,2,5,2,6,10,8,2,4,2,10,3,4,4,5,7,4,5,1,3,10,7,8,3,1,7,4,7,6,0,7,3,3,7,5,3,6,3,2,6,7,8,4,5,8,8,5,2,1,8,10,5,2,2,8,1,9,6,10,8,9,5,2,1,10,0,9,8,0,8,10,9,2,2,1,7,0,8,6,7,5,2,8,1,2,3,0,2,1,7,2,10,1,4,6,0,9,6,9,8,5,10,8,9,8,6,2,0,3,10,6,1,3,6,8,2,1,3,5,8,3,0,9,6,8,6,5,9,8,1,3,3,3,8,3,9,7,2,8,2,7,2,4,5,6,4,4,6,6,2,2,2,6,7,4,7,1,9,6,8,5,5,7,3,6,6,8,8,9,5,3,6,2,5,4,4,6,5,4,4,8,5,6,4,7,6,5,4,5,1,6,10,10,6,9,4,8,5,6,9,9,0,6,10,1,7,8,6,6,3,7,6,6,7,9,2,2,10,7,8,6,4,8,5,2,3,4,5,9,5,2,5,7,9,7,3,1,9,1,8,8,8,6,7,4,5,6,5,8,5,4,2,9,5,7,1,8,8,2,4,3,6,4,7,2,6,2,1,8,5,8,10,7,2,9,3,2,5,2,6,0,5,3,1,4,8,9,3,9,4,7,9,0,3,9,3,4,9,7,1,3,1,8,1,0,3,4,7,6,3,1,3,1,9,8,8,10,3,1,4,9,3,9,8,3,6,5,5,6,6,3,1,1,7,9,2,4,2,6,1,1,9,9,2,7,10,0,7,3,9,9,0,0,4,3,2,3,3,8,6,8,1,10,9,4,7,9,6,5,2,6,2,7,2,1,9,8,6,9,9,4,3,3,4,4,8,9,10,9,7,5,1,7,6,0,5,9,9,5,9,3,9,2,2,8,8,2,10,6,10,1,5,8,10,5,2,5,6,4,4,9,2,7,8,1,9,3,1,6,5,9,10,5,2,9,5,2,7,2,1,2,7,5,0,2,7,5,7,2,2,2,8,0,10,9,2,8,6,5,8,4,6,1,6,7,1,5,9,5,10,7,9,8,5,8,0,9,6,1,7,4,10,0,8,9,8,4,6,8,6,9,8,2,7,6,4,6,9,3,7,6,8,10,1,8,7,4,5,1,2,1,7,4,4,2,1,3,8,1,3,7,4,6,6,3,0,8,1,2,6,8,5,5,1,8,4,2,6,7,6,7,8,7,6,3,1,4,10,5,7,6,1,2,5,9,0,4,9,6,7,8,5,0,9,5,2,2,4,10,0,7,5,4,3,9,7,7,8,10,5,7,10,0,2,8,4,4,1,2,6,6,0,6,8,4,3,7,5,1,4,5,9,2,9,4,3,4,4,4,2,1,9,7,2,2,1,5,8,8,3,2,5,4,7,3,2,1,8,6,3,5,5,8,4,4,0,0,2,10,7,8,8,4,5,0,9,5,5,0,7,1,1,0,4,1,8,
    6,5,0,3,7,6,2,4,4,3,1,1,9,2,1,7,8,1,10,6,3,7,5,5,6,4,1,2,0,8,4,6,2,1,4,6,5,3,1,5,9,4,8,4,8,1,3,6,5,7,4,1,4,4,6,9,7,2,4,7,3,4,1,5,6,7,9,9,8,5,5,8,7,8,6,9,5,4,10,5,10,2,5,7,8,0,8,6,1,8,1,1,7,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,5,1,7,3,6,2,7,0,10,3,6,9,0,4,6,2,4,7,1,3,2,9,5,9,9,7,8,9,6,3,7,2,5,1,8,9,9,8,7,2,3,3,8,3,5,0,3,8,6,1,4,4,1,7,3,0,1,7,3,7,0,4,4,2,4,3,10,2,2,9,4,0,5,8,9,5,7,9,4,3,1,2,2,9,4,7,6,0,6,0,3,10,6,0,3,9,5,0,9,9,1,5,3,10,4,4,9,7,6,3,3,2,8,1,6,1,1,10,6,6,2,8,8,4,4,1,1,4,4,1,7,3,5,10,10,10,6,8,2,1,0,9,5,10,7,3,9,5,2,3,8,4,4,0,4,6,6,9,3,7,4,9,9,1,3,6,8,5,9,5,1,3,3,3,4,9,1,9,2,7,1,0,2,7,0,1,0,4,5,7,9,5,8,10,5,9,8,4,1,5,3,2,1,9,5,7,9,7,0,2,4,1,7,5,0,7,8,5,8,7,3,8,2,4,4,1,2,6,0,4,9,9,2,10,7,0,8,9,9,7,5,1,1,9,8,1,7,6,3,4,3,10,4,9,8,7,9,7,9,10,3,10,8,2,9,1,0,8,5,2,6,0,1,8,2,7,9,8,3,9,6,4,2,3,7,2,8,3,7,1,2,9,6,7,5,8,9,2,0,8,7,7,7,4,1,1,6,8,8,9,6,10,5,5,5,9,2,5,8,4,7,6,9,4,2,6,8,3,0,9,8,5,7,2,6,4,4,9,8,1,1,9,10,2,6,8,0,0,6,2,3,4,4,2,1,7,6,2,2,8,9,7,6,3,6,10,2,4,6,6,6,2,2,8,1,9,0,0,7,4,4,8,7,5,2,5,6,5,10,2,9,7,7,10,1,5,1,9,8,6,10,6,7,6,9,0,7,5,3,10,2,0,1,1,9,4,9,1,6,8,8,0,10,9,3,6,1,2,4,6,4,7,9,9,6,4,9,0,4,1,4,1,3,0,6,5,3,7,2,2,9,1,6,6,2,3,4,7,4,9,7,7,9,0,3,2,7,8,9,9,4,9,7,7,4,6,1,5,5,3,3,3,4,4,6,5,4,7,1,3,7,5,3,5,3,5,5,10,3,1,6,8,10,9,3,7,8,2,8,5,1,10,8,7,9,6,3,7,8,8,5,5,4,1,5,3,4,1,7,8,9,8,10,9,8,1,10,6,8,3,4,4,5,10,0,8,4,5,10,8,9,6,8,8,1,3,7,1,1,1,3,2,5,2,2,5,0,3,
    2,2,10,1,7,9,4,7,9,7,7,10,2,3,2,1,0,3,5,8,8,9,5,2,1,6,6,2,5,9,9,2,2,4,3,1,8,9,7,7,5,1,1,7,1,5,9,6,1,0,1,3,2,7,3,5,9,1,8,7,4,1,2,4,9,4,7,6,1,2,0,8,1,7,9,5,9,2,4,4,6,1,6,2,8,6,3,3,1,6,7,1,6,10,4,1,6,4,3,8,7,9,10,3,5,5,5,5,2,1,5,5,2,5,7,6,9,5,5,10,3,4,9,0,0,8,5,8,4,6,0,2,5,0,2,2,9,7,3,7,6,3,5,4,3,5,7,2,9,9,2,7,4,3,6,9,7,0,6,9,9,4,4,6,1,5,2,0,5,2,8,9,2,0,4,7,0,5,8,3,3,4,7,1,7,7,3,3,0,7,9,8,7,0,7,6,9,7,6,2,4,9,1,3,0,7,9,7,7,8,10,5,8,6,3,2,3,0,3,10,8,3,2,7,1,5,4,2,1,10,4,1,7,3,2,2,0,7,1,5,4,5,2,5,9,2,1,4,6,4,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,7,4,1,2,2,7,3,8,6,8,2,5,8,5,7,3,8,2,2,4,1,8,8,1,4,8,8,2,10,3,6,1,4,2,4,7,8,9,4,6,8,2,3,1,5,1,3,4,0,3,1,2,4,8,10,9,6,2,7,2,8,3,2,6,1,2,5,6,10,3,6,6,5,6,4,10,5,5,1,4,7,6,2,7,6,9,8,4,8,9,7,7,6,9,7,1,6,4,6,4,2,6,9,5,4,1,6,6,5,8,5,1,1,6,5,9,3,6,1,2,6,7,4,2,2,5,9,7,1,9,9,5,10,5,10,8,3,7,5,4,10,4,8,2,3,0,8,0,10,8,3,5,3,5,7,7,6,8,7,9,3,9,4,7,8,8,5,9,2,6,0,0,3,5,3,6,6,4,2,7,2,4,6,4,10,8,4,8,8,10,6,9,4,7,1,8,9,3,1,6,4,8,6,6,7,10,5,3,9,5,7,7,8,7,9,2,7,3,1,2,5,4,1,1,4,2,6,10,8,6,7,0,8,1,5,8,3,2,5,1,8,4,2,1,7,4,7,4,2,5,1,4,7,3,5,3,1,1,3,7,3,5,7,2,2,9,3,9,2,3,2,4,7,6,3,4,3,0,2,8,0,10,1,2,2,7,5,9,4,1,10,9,5,7,4,3,6,7,5,9,5,2,8,3,1,9,3,8,1,5,6,3,10,8,1,7,10,1,5,1,1,5,5,10,6,2,7,2,4,9,7,3,2,1,9,7,3,3,1,3,5,2,7,4,3,7,5,4,10,6,8,9,4,9,6,9,2,7,0,2,7,
    8,2,2,9,7,2,5,1,8,9,3,3,8,9,8,3,5,4,5,0,0,6,8,1,7,9,10,5,7,0,9,2,6,2,0,5,5,9,5,8,3,8,2,5,8,4,5,6,9,9,7,8,2,3,3,2,9,2,8,7,0,7,4,4,7,5,3,1,2,8,0,4,7,4,9,10,10,1,6,2,6,2,1,2,5,0,8,2,3,1,5,3,5,4,2,3,7,6,10,2,9,7,5,1,4,3,4,7,2,7,3,6,5,8,1,2,2,3,2,0,4,9,3,9,10,7,7,1,9,6,5,10,6,7,6,4,10,4,7,4,4,3,3,8,10,5,8,7,7,8,7,7,7,1,3,9,4,7,4,9,9,7,1,4,8,6,5,4,7,6,0,7,5,4,4,9,4,7,10,8,4,6,10,8,6,10,7,8,2,9,9,5,9,9,9,5,10,8,3,9,10,7,5,8,3,10,7,4,3,7,8,0,4,10,9,8,9,8,5,2,5,7,5,2,9,6,2,4,10,6,7,7,9,7,4,7,7,10,8,1,7,1,3,6,7,4,1,5,1,5,2,4,6,10,10,10,2,2,4,7,9,6,4,9,4,6,5,10,8,0,7,6,3,6,6,7,5,9,4,6,2,7,3,1,8,9,0,0,9,5,1,6,8,7,7,1,7,0,1,9,0,5,0,0,0,4,5,9,1,4,1,3,0,2,10,6,2,9,5,6,1,5,5,8,1,8,5,2,3,9,5,7,7,6,1,6,3,8,0,6,1,2,4,2,10,5,10,7,9,3,10,2,5,5,3,6,10,0,4,3,8,8,2,5,4,8,5,10,1,6,2,4,6,7,2,5,4,6,9,6,10,3,9,4,1,3,5,8,1,5,5,10,2,9,8,3,4,6,7,10,9,10,0,5,4,8,2,0,4,3,1,2,7,7,7,5,5,1,5,5,7,7,6,2,5,3,2,3,4,9,1,2,10,6,10,0,2,3,8,6,4,1,4,5,5,2,9,7,0,5,9,3,1,6,6,8,4,1,2,5,8,6,5,3,4,2,6,5,8,1,2,8,2,4,5,5,3,0,5,7,4,1,8,5,4,8,2,1,4,1,5,4,9,1,5,7,2,7,2,1,4,3,2,3,7,3,0,1,3,2,5,2,8,7,5,1,9,3,6,3,2,5,8,6,9,6,2,6,5,6,7,5,8,4,9,8,1,3,4,6,8,0,2,8,2,7,6,1,3,10,1,2,0,0,6,3,4,2,2,2,1,9,5,3,5,3,5,
    5,3,7,7,1,3,6,10,6,7,8,4,3,8,4,3,8,10,4,5,6,7,6,0,5,4,6,6,9,2,1,9,6,9,10,0,8,3,5,10,2,4,3,2,2,0,6,9,0,5,7,10,6,4,8,8,1,4,2,10,4,8,9,10,6,1,1,9,3,6,5,7,8,10,2,4,9,9,10,1,0,2,7,3,2,7,3,2,10,7,4,9,5,6,4,4,5,5,5,1,8,5,2,6,1,4,3,1,10,1,3,1,2,5,6,5,9,4,3,1,2,0,7,2,2,2,3,4,3,6,4,3,8,1,0,6,8,8,9,4,1,2,0,8,10,8,6,2,9,3,8,9,1,2,0,2,10,7,9,9,9,8,1,7,9,7,8,9,8,7,5,5,1,10,7,5,3,9,0,5,2,10,3,2,0,9,4,9,7,10,2,1,0,7,5,4,1,7,6,3,6,2,6,8,4,10,8,5,8,3,5,6,4,8,7,6,9,5,5,10,7,3,4,4,0,3,5,4,2,3,1,8,8,7,3,0,0,7,1,3,3,9,2,8,1,7,0,9,9,4,6,1,6,5,10,7,9,1,2,7,4,10,8,2,10,2,5,2,9,2,5,6,10,5,4,1,8,10,7,9,1,4,4,0,2,2,10,9,6,8,10,7,8,9,3,3,7,5,4,6,8,3,10,7,1,7,3,7,6,4,5,4,9,6,7,6,1,7,0,2,5,8,9,7,7,10,1,9,6,7,7,5,8,7,3,5,7,8,2,7,0,6,8,5,8,3,4,5,8,9,2,2,5,7,0,4,0,1,6,8,1,2,1,5,2,5,7,4,3,8,3,4,6,3,3,1,7,4,6,0,2,4,4,1,2,4,4,0,2,1,5,2,7,4,9,7,7,9,9,0,3,3,7,7,3,1,4,1,10,3,9,6,6,5,6,4,10,6,1,2,5,0,7,7,2,0,5,4,1,6,0,9,6,9,2,3,1,8,6,1,3,4,4,6,7,0,6,6,9,8,4,9,3,8,8,5,1,4,8,9,1,5,0,2,1,1,0,10,4,
    6,3,3,2,5,5,3,2,2,7,7,5,5,5,3,3,8,4,6,10,4,9,7,4,9,8,3,1,0,1,1,8,5,0,8,3,8,8,3,3,3,3,6,7,1,1,3,4,3,8,8,5,10,0,7,5,9,7,5,8,6,7,5,5,9,2,8,6,7,4,9,6,8,8,6,2,0,0,1,2,1,3,2,1,2,3,3,3,4,2,2,7,7,6,10,5,4,1,5,9,0,1,4,5,3,9,10,4,1,0,7,4,10,3,2,9,9,0,9,3,6,1,3,2,5,5,7,3,0,6,8,3,2,6,9,4,5,2,3,5,6,2,2,1,0,2,6,5,2,2,6,5,10,7,9,2,1,4,7,4,9,3,6,7,5,5,4,1,4,3,6,7,10,5,3,5,8,2,6,6,3,5,8,3,7,0,4,2,4,5,8,5,3,4,6,8,5,3,9,4,4,4,4,6,10,0,5,5,7,10,5,5,1,9,4,5,5,7,9,0,8,2,4,8,4,4,10,7,0,5,10,9,5,8,2,9,6,9,1,1,9,10,7,9,9,2,8,6,5,8,2,4,6,9,10,8,7,8,8,9,10,7,7,4,1,10,1,10,5,9,9,8,1,4,4,1,4,3,9,8,3,8,0,0,9,6,3,2,10,7,4,2,1,2,7,1,7,9,7,8,2,2,1,6,2,9,7,2,3,3,9,8,5,0,8,3,8,6,1,8,3,2,1,5,5,1,8,7,5,6,9,4,4,8,5,1,3,6,6,4,8,7,5,1,6,8,8,7,7,5,3,5,0,1,7,2,8,4,1,6,9,7,7,9,3,4,3,7,9,7,10,6,5,8,1,8,2,5,2,5,4,5,6,1,1,9,4,0,8,3,8,4,5,1,4,5,10,5,5,3,7,8,7,5,8,6,4,8,3,6,5,0,9,5,1,2,5,0,2,9,7,3,5,5,8,5,3,2,4,10,2,9,5,6,1,0,6,4,6,9,8,4,1,6,4,3,8,10,4,2,3,3,7,8,10,4,8,7,10,2,7,7,8,2,3,8,0,4,9,9,2,5,2,4,5,6,4,8,5,1,4,8,4,7,2,1,0,0,5,5,3,9,3,2,1,4,6,6,4,7,7,5,6,4,2,1,5,0,2,4,5,6,4,3,4,8,7,2,2,4,9,6,4,6,7,10,2,8,10,3,3,9,4,4,8,3,2,7,4,2,9,5,2,5,6,3,0,6,10,3,9,1,2,9,9,1,8,9,1,2,4,7,0,9,9,5,10,4,9,2,7,7,1,5,6,2,7,1,5,9,1,0,7,6,3,4,9,6,6,1,3,1,9,3,5,5,1,4,3,9,2,6,8,8,10,7,6,7,6,10,7,9,7,7,1,5,5,8,6,9,7,6,1,0,10,10,6,8,2,5,1,4,9,8,4,2,8,1,8,8,2,8,8,3,6,7,6,1,4,6,3,2,6,8,3,8,7,2,2,4,6,9,4,5,4,0,5,5,10,8,1,8,2,0,8,4,9,5,5,3,8,2,9,8,6,1,
    5,7,6,3,5,8,0,6,3,6,2,4,5,4,9,3,3,10,10,8,1,3,4,3,0,4,8,8,10,2,5,5,4,6,3,2,10,6,6,0,6,9,1,2,3,9,9,4,3,9,6,2,5,5,6,6,1,1,2,9,9,6,5,5,3,2,7,9,2,3,10,5,4,7,1,1,7,1,2,2,8,4,6,10,3,7,8,2,5,0,4,5,1,6,5,9,1,9,3,8,4,2,9,3,6,5,3,4,2,5,8,8,6,8,4,2,1,2,10,5,7,10,10,5,9,1,10,3,8,3,8,9,4,2,8,5,9,3,4,4,4,3,7,5,9,7,4,5,7,3,7,4,3,2,1,6,2,5,0,4,5,5,7,5,9,7,5,8,10,5,6,3,4,2,7,4,7,0,7,9,4,0,9,1,7,2,9,9,8,1,10,10,7,10,4,6,5,7,6,6,1,2,8,9,3,7,7,4,3,2,4,2,9,3,1,4,10,1,1,3,5,5,7,5,4,7,10,4,0,3,2,1,1,4,7,5,9,3,3,8,4,6,8,2,6,0,5,4,2,10,10,4,1,10,5,6,7,10,7,5,1,10,2,6,4,9,8,6,9,5,6,4,5,8,1,9,3,9,4,4,3,8,8,1,3,2,0,2,2,4,4,6,0,2,1,4,10,2,3,2,9,8,8,4,2,7,3,5,0,4,7,3,4,9,7,4,5,10,5,1,6,4,4,1,7,2,0,3,10,3,4,3,0,5,1,2,1,8,10,7,7,9,7,2,6,9,2,8,9,5,5,8,4,1,6,3,1,6,10,10,9,5,3,3,8,7,2,7,4,1,9,10,2,8,3,3,1,4,5,2,2,6,8,8,7,3,9,9,9,8,4,5,4,9,0,5,2,9,3,0,4,7,4,5,2,2,2,6,6,1,8,9,8,1,2,1,6,4,1,2,2,8,1,7,9,2,9,7,7,0,2,9,7,7,0,3,2,1,10,0,5,10,9,5,5,8,3,8,5,9,3,8,9,1,4,1,1,3,5,3,4,3,4,6,3,4,10,5,3,8,1,6,9,2,0,3,6,9,4,6,4,6,4,9,5,3,4,2,8,7,3,2,1,4,4,2,2,5,2,6,7,6,6,0,7,0,0,1,6,2,3,2,4,1,0,5,6,6,6,7,4,9,8,4,1,9,8,4,5,5,2,6,7,3,5,6,2,9,3,1,3,7,0,5,7,4,8,6,3,3,4,4,0,5,0,9,1,8,7,5,4,5,0,2,3,7,10,5,8,8,3,3,10,4,3,5,9,9,10,10,4,0,4,6,4,8,5,10,0,5,9,7,1,4,8,8,5,7,9,5,4,7,7,7,1,1,8,3,0,9,10,9,7,0,6,4,5,
    1,6,0,6,4,7,8,6,1,6,5,4,4,2,5,8,4,6,9,3,4,4,3,3,10,8,1,6,4,1,8,7,6,0,8,9,2,7,5,3,4,7,6,5,7,9,7,6,2,8,2,9,6,8,4,3,7,3,0,8,8,1,9,2,9,7,7,6,5,3,2,7,1,5,8,9,9,1,9,9,8,2,3,3,4,1,6,7,6,5,7,10,1,6,9,1,2,3,9,8,7,1,2,0,5,6,8,1,6,7,6,4,1,1,3,5,2,8,7,3,5,1,3,8,6,7,1,3,6,6,7,6,5,5,7,5,4,8,8,7,1,9,1,3,2,6,2,7,6,0,9,7,9,0,2,6,9,0,1,1,2,7,6,0,3,6,3,9,6,4,0,6,3,3,4,6,8,8,7,2,6,10,4,8,3,4,8,2,8,9,6,7,8,0,3,0,5,3,5,8,8,9,5,6,3,6,9,2,3,7,5,1,9,5,7,6,8,7,3,5,7,2,0,6,6,3,8,3,9,7,7,8,7,9,6,4,8,5,2,6,5,9,1,10,2,10,6,8,4,5,6,9,2,0,5,0,2,5,5,6,9,2,2,8,4,4,9,3,6,4,9,4,5,10,3,4,4,7,1,1,3,0,9,10,2,9,9,7,7,9,3,3,1,8,10,1,0,7,7,3,8,10,8,3,9,0,4,4,10,4,1,8,3,1,7,4,10,9,6,1,9,9,3,7,7,5,5,2,9,2,2,0,0,9,7,0,6,5,9,8,1,9,7,5,8,5,3,1,5,3,2,2,6,3,5,6,5,9,4,4,10,9,7,8,2,2,7,7,2,1,9,10,3,6,7,10,3,6,8,1,5,2,9,6,0,5,5,8,9,2,3,4,9,3,7,3,8,4,2,3,0,2,6,3,3,1,3,10,8,7,9,2,5,4,2,3,7,8,1,5,6,4,8,8,1,10,9,9,2,0,6,0,9,1,6,5,2,9,10,8,1,9,3,2,9,4,3,1,2,1,1,7,1,3,6,9,3,3,7,2,2,0,6,4,2,8,10,0,1,7,5,8,4,3,5,6,4,5,7,6,7,5,10,7,2,10,4,10,5,1,3,9,2,9,8,0,6,5,3,1,4,3,6,2,2,5,4,0,0,9,3,5,5,5,0,9,0,8,2,9,6,5,5,8,5,10,9,1,6,0,4,9,7,2,9,
    4,2,9,9,4,9,3,1,5,1,9,8,5,2,9,1,6,4,1,10,9,4,1,6,7,6,7,7,4,5,9,0,3,2,4,5,2,8,4,2,2,8,1,1,3,5,9,9,1,1,8,6,4,5,8,5,7,9,4,7,0,9,6,2,2,9,6,3,2,0,9,6,9,1,5,7,4,2,9,10,9,8,9,6,8,3,1,5,7,1,4,3,9,2,5,5,9,9,8,2,0,8,7,7,9,1,5,2,2,7,8,4,0,8,4,1,8,7,4,8,8,1,4,2,7,8,8,8,0,0,7,8,2,3,9,9,1,8,0,7,2,6,9,8,4,2,5,5,9,4,10,1,9,7,10,4,3,8,2,2,4,2,9,8,5,3,1,2,8,10,0,10,8,3,3,8,0,0,3,4,2,0,2,7,2,10,1,0,6,6,5,6,3,0,9,4,1,7,1,10,1,3,2,2,2,6,1,3,0,3,7,4,6,8,5,9,4,1,4,4,3,8,3,0,6,2,7,9,7,2,5,5,2,5,9,10,6,1,9,10,8,8,2,9,10,5,4,2,5,9,8,8,9,3,5,10,8,10,0,6,4,2,1,9,5,4,1,4,2,8,10,2,0,2,1,5,2,6,5,3,8,6,2,7,0,10,6,3,7,6,2,4,8,9,8,6,7,6,8,6,7,6,4,0,4,6,0,6,9,8,7,3,4,4,4,2,10,3,1,3,5,0,1,7,3,10,3,1,5,0,7,8,6,1,10,2,7,4,3,4,0,10,1,0,6,5,0,10,0,4,1,3,6,3,9,8,3,9,0,0,5,7,1,1,3,7,4,2,1,9,3,4,2,6,5,9,8,2,10,6,4,10,5,4,4,4,6,5,5,4,6,8,8,9,1,6,3,9,3,3,6,6,1,2,8,7,8,5,3,7,10,10,1,10,7,3,8,2,1,2,3,4,2,9,6,7,3,3,3,5,0,3,9,2,5,10,2,8,3,10,7,10,8,6,8,4,8,8,4,4,2,4,8,3,2,1,3,8,10,3,1,10,7,2,8,2,8,7,6,
    3,7,7,3,0,5,5,0,9,9,7,5,7,8,3,5,8,2,4,6,1,8,2,5,9,3,5,6,9,2,7,2,4,2,9,6,4,7,9,6,5,4,3,8,4,5,6,6,2,1,3,8,5,10,2,2,9,8,1,5,7,1,7,1,10,8,3,3,3,2,9,9,3,7,7,3,4,6,0,9,7,6,5,7,4,8,7,2,7,1,4,9,8,1,7,8,3,9,5,6,6,3,7,9,6,6,5,3,6,2,5,3,5,4,2,1,4,8,6,1,4,0,0,4,2,1,7,3,3,10,10,3,0,8,1,1,6,5,1,9,5,4,5,2,3,8,5,6,3,5,1,9,6,8,5,8,5,8,1,3,1,3,0,2,2,2,8,6,5,5,9,5,8,0,0,4,3,4,9,2,6,0,10,4,1,7,5,2,6,9,6,0,3,5,9,0,6,3,4,8,6,2,5,2,2,8,7,9,0,1,4,7,7,10,0,1,5,0,9,4,9,4,0,4,10,7,1,4,5,2,8,7,0,9,9,3,4,3,0,2,10,2,3,1,2,5,9,9,6,2,7,0,8,9,0,7,8,4,4,6,4,8,7,8,10,1,7,8,8,9,7,6,3,2,0,3,9,4,2,10,6,5,8,1,6,9,0,5,1,5,5,1,1,8,1,3,1,4,5,4,9,3,9,2,3,9,3,6,8,2,2,9,2,6,5,6,5,2,5,6,4,7,1,1,0,10,6,8,1,9,5,3,9,6,9,8,4,1,7,2,3,9,1,8,6,7,8,9,1,4,1,6,4,3,2,3,10,8,6,3,7,1,0,2,1,0,4,1,10,3,4,10,5,9,1,10,4,1,5,5,5,2,2,1,4,0,6,9,8,9,9,7,1,9,5,5,5,6,9,3,6,6,6,9,6,1,3,5,8,1,8,5,5,9,8,8,5,5,2,3,2,7,3,8,3,6,10,6,7,7,1,8,2,9,5,1,3,4,6,4,1,6,0,1,5,3,3,1,6,8,2,1,9,2,5,9,5,8,2,6,1,6,7,9,9,4,4,3,4,1,5,9,4,4,7,8,8,6,6,2,4,8,8,3,5,7,6,1,7,6,2,6,4,1,6,5,10,3,4,5,7,3,8,7,8,5,4,6,1,2,4,0,6,5,9,7,2,1,5,9,5,9,6,2,5,7,10,9,7,2,4,6,0,1,4,6,9,7,4,3,6,5,2,10,6,4,8,2,5,4,2,9,8,3,4,5,2,9,3,3,8,1,0,8,1,7,1,9,7,9,5,9,7,9,9,5,9,2,2,4,3,8,0,7,3,2,8,4,5,7,10,10,4,2,8,4,7,7,2,8,6,10,9,10,3,9,2,6,4,0,5,1,7,0,3,0,8,0,1,1,5,8,2,1,4,
    8,4,2,6,0,9,9,8,2,2,2,1,4,6,3,5,5,8,6,9,3,2,1,3,3,5,6,5,1,4,7,3,5,8,8,2,1,10,10,7,3,2,9,9,4,8,1,8,10,3,3,8,3,7,5,7,5,4,10,7,0,10,2,2,1,6,2,10,9,4,6,4,10,8,2,0,8,3,8,8,1,4,3,5,7,6,6,6,7,9,2,5,2,6,1,8,1,6,1,4,9,5,9,2,5,8,6,6,9,4,3,0,8,9,6,1,9,9,8,9,2,8,4,1,3,7,6,7,9,8,9,0,9,5,2,9,6,10,9,2,2,2,2,8,2,9,8,6,2,5,6,5,0,5,1,0,2,1,6,3,8,1,5,1,7,9,4,10,7,9,9,2,4,7,3,9,9,4,4,10,7,3,3,3,6,10,8,10,6,9,2,8,7,8,5,3,7,4,1,6,3,2,2,1,3,6,7,2,9,6,2,7,6,8,5,5,5,9,6,9,7,1,9,2,10,3,2,10,9,8,7,8,8,1,8,8,6,8,1,9,3,6,9,4,7,5,5,3,0,9,3,2,3,7,7,6,5,8,1,10,10,2,3,8,3,9,3,7,7,10,0,4,10,1,7,1,6,6,1,8,7,6,3,1,9,5,10,9,9,9,8,0,5,7,7,9,3,3,7,6,6,4,9,9,7,5,8,8,9,9,5,7,3,3,7,0,6,3,4,4,9,8,3,6,2,7,9,3,0,5,1,6,6,1,5,0,4,1,7,6,4,9,4,7,7,6,9,8,0,8,8,6,7,3,0,6,7,3,10,8,3,6,8,4,9,0,7,7,2,8,8,3,9,6,7,7,4,0,10,2,1,3,6,4,9,4,4,10,2,2,8,3,1,9,8,1,0,2,8,4,3,9,3,5,5,1,7,3,4,3,8,4,9,6,4,1,4,4,1,8,5,2,10,8,2,7,0,10,10,3,3,9,2,1,7,8,2,0,10,2,7,7,4,4,2,5,8,3,1,3,3,3,1,10,2,6,6,8,10,2,8,1,1,7,5,8,6,3,2,7,9,5,3,2,8,3,8,6,2,10,4,7,2,4,10,6,6,5,7,1,3,0,6,3,3,7,5,6,3,10,1,2,2,7,3,1,0,8,6,7,7,5,2,7,2,7,0,7,2,8,7,7,2,7,1,8,5,6,1,0,3,6,10,7,0,4,8,4,2,1,9,2,1,1,7,4,8,2,1,7,5,8,2,6,5,1,7,7,1,9,1,4,1,7,5,7,3,4,8,7,7,2,3,2,10,0,2,2,5,9,3,10,9,5,1,1,6,4,5,4,7,6,9,3,5,2,0,1,5,3,8,1,6,9,3,10,8,8,3,2,4,4,3,5,9,5,10,7,1,5];

}

var beforeTime:Date
var afterTime:Date
var arr1:Array
var arr2:Array
var i:int
var j:int

for (j=0;j<10;j++){
    arr1 = getArray()
    beforeTime = new Date()
    arr1 = arr1.filter(myFilter)
    afterTime = new Date()
    trace('mine'+(afterTime.time-beforeTime.time))
}


for (j=0;j<10;j++){
    arr2 = getArray()
    beforeTime = new Date()
    arr2.sort();
    for (i = arr2.length -1; 1 <= i; --i ){
        if ( arr2[i-1] == arr2[i] ){
            arr2.splice(i-1,1);
        }
    }
    afterTime = new Date()
    trace('his' +(afterTime.time-beforeTime.time))
}


function myFilter(element:*, index:int, arr:Array):Boolean {
    return (index==arr.lastIndexOf(element));
}


// outputs
mine4
mine4
mine4
mine3
mine4
mine4
mine3
mine4
mine4
mine3
his192
his189
his188
his188
his190
his189
his189
his191
his194
his190
```

Comment: Cleaner yes, faster - no. In my test this method is 8 times slower than splice. Also it genertate new array when splice modify the existing. I test it with sorted array with 10K elements

Comment: @AzzyElvul is *faster* a metric that is useful here? is this used in a performance-sensitive area of code? or are you simply pre-optimizing for the sake of optimizing?

Comment: @AzzyElvul on the contrary, your method is 3 to 6 times slower, since the array HAS to be sorted, while with the_asman's method that's not necessary.

Comment: With 100000 elements it's even worse, see for yourself: https://gist.github.com/creynders/5110583

Comment: You are right. For unsorted arrays your method is faster, for sorted arrays it is not.