# Remove duplicate values from arraycollection in flex4

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection, filterfunction

This is my arraycollection

```
o = JSON.parse(event.result.toString());

jsonarray = new ArrayCollection(o as Array);
```

in this array i have a duplicate values of product name, so i  wants to remove duplicacy.\
my code is here,its not working please let me know, i am a flex beginner. thanx in advance.

```
function removeDuplicates(item:Object):Boolean 
{
    var returnValue:Boolean = false;
    if (!myObject.hasOwnProperty(item.ProductName))
    {
        myObject[item.ProductName] = item;
        returnValue = true;
    }
    prodArray.push(myObject);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: var o:Object;              please reply ASAP. its urgent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flash as3 How do I remove duplicates in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997822/flash-as3-how-do-i-remove-duplicates-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Call the filterCollection method given below and in that use the filterfunction to remove duplicates

```
private var tempObj:Object = {};

private function filterCollection():void {
    // assign the filter function
    jsonarray.filterFunction = removeDuplicates;
    //refresh the collection
    jsonarray.refresh();
}

private function removeDuplicates(item:Object):Boolean {
    return (tempObj.hasOwnProperty(item.ProductName) ? false : tempObj[item.ProductName] = item && true);
}
```